# Python Flask displaying username in URL

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working through Oreilly's an introduction to flask, and have been stuck on a part for a while.  Its with generating a dynamic url based off the users profile.

**My views.py**

```
@main.route('/user/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user == None:
        flash(user)
        return redirect(url_for('auth.register'))
    return render_template('/main/profile.html', user=user)
```

**models.py**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
```

When I visit a page, I get None as a username and redircted.  If i change

**My views.py**

```
@main.route('/user/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user(username):
    user = Current_user
```

I get the page to show with the username visible using  {{user.username }}, but the url looks like

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/main/user/%3Capp.models.User%20object%20at%200x7f31fa279550%3E
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you generating your URL? Also, `None` should be checked for identity, not equality: `if user is None:`.

Comment: <a href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=g.user) }}"> Profile </a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the user object as the value for username to `url_for`. When you do this, the user object is converted into a string representation that's inserted into the URL. Your call to `filter_by` looks for a username with that value. What you want to pass is just the username.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=g.user.username) }}">Profile</a>
```