# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, url, routes, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying display my current users username in the url when the user accesses settings page. However when I try to access the settings page from index, I get 404  error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check 
your spelling and try again.
```

and the undefined error while accessing any other page from navigation.
My layout.html(concerned part):

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user', Users_username=user.username) }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer"> Settings</a>
```

Models.py:

```
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
       __tablename__ = "users"
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
       email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
       image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
       password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
       posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

Function in Routes.py:

```
@app.route("/user/<Users_username>" , methods=["GET", "POST"])
def user(Users_username):

user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username).first()
if user is None:
    flash(user)
    return redirect(url_for('register'))
return render_template("settings.html", user=user)
```

I have also tried every single step, ever single thing in this article  but nothing pays off [Python Flask displaying username in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929226/python-flask-displaying-username-in-url)
The only difference it makes is when I change layout.html from

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user', Users_username=user.username) }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer">Settings</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user', Users_username=g.user) }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer">Settings</a>
```

I dont get undefined error while accessing any other page from navigation but still get 404 error.
Thanks in advance.I have been stuck on this from 3 days, no article or video pays off.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of research and desire for answers, reading multiple articles watching countless videos, just randomly tried this in layout.html which worked!!

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user', Users_username = current_user.username ) }}" 
target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Settings</a>
```

Now no need for database queries in settings function!